# Is there a way to see the what percentage you are in a particular tag?

Tags: discussion

I know I can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) to see my rank in a particular tag. But is there a way to see at what percent I am in?

Comment: In short: no such thing. And something similar was asked, though I might have missed your request, in which case please explain better what you want and I will reopen this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/527106/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-what-percentage-you-are-in-a-particular-tag?tagname=java&UserId=1475228) gives you that result:

```sql
; with tagleague as 
(
-- build score and count per user
select p.owneruserid
     , sum(score) as score
     , count(*) as posts
     , rank() over(order by sum(score) desc) as tagrank
from posts p  
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) -- questions have tags
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname = ##tagname:string?java##
and p.owneruserid is not null
and posttypeid in (1,2) -- Q/A 
group by owneruserid
)

select owneruserid as [User Link]
     , ( cast(tagrank as decimal) 
       / (select count(*) from tagleague) 
       * 100 ) as perc
     , (select count(*) from tagleague) as total
     , tagrank
from tagleague
where owneruserid = ##userid:int?1475228##
```

When run today your percentage is:

[image: percentage of ranking in tag]

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated weekly, in the weekend.